# sum time for dtype: object in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have object data in df in the 'czas_oczekiwania' column
[image]

when grouping, I want to have the sum of times for individual days

```
ph3=ph1.groupby([pd.to_datetime(ph1['data']).dt.to_period('D'), 'typ'])['czas_oczekiwania'].sum()
```

but my result is [image]
How can I change this?

Comment: do `pd1['czas_oczekiwania'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd1['czas_oczekiwania'])` before your code and you'll be fine.

Comment: Please post code, **data, and results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @QuangHoang Hoang now I have almost perfect
data                  typ         
`2024-02-01  Przychodzące   0 days 00:52:07
                     Wychodzące     0 days 00:11:28`
how can I remove "0 days", i want only time

Comment: `.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`?

Comment: Unfortunately I got error 'TimedeltaProperties' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***i think you need datetime module and time converting with apply_dataframe***

```
import datetime

result = (
    ph3
    .dt
    .components[["hours","minutes","seconds"]]
    .apply(lambda x: datetime.time(hour=x[0], minute=x[1], second=x[2]), axis=1)
)
result
```